# C# How to Fix Error: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

In the code below, I'm trying to validate the Textbox (txt_quantity and txt_discount)

But instead of getting this `MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty");` I'm getting the error of

> ('Input string was not in a correct format.')

Did i forgot something here?

- txt_quantity(INTEGER)
- txt_discount(DECIMAL)

  ```
  decimal Discount, DiscountTotal, Discountgiven, Total;
  int Cost, Quantity, ID;       
  byte[] data;
  public void Imagedisplay()
  {
      using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
      {
          using (var selects = new SqlCommand("Select * from employee_product where Codeitem =@Codeitem ", con))
          {
              selects.Parameters.Add("@Codeitem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text;
              using (var reader = selects.ExecuteReader())
              {
                  while (reader.Read())
                  {
                      data = (byte[])reader["Image"];

                      Cost = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Unitcost"]);
                      Convert.ToInt32(DiscountTotal);
                  //  This is where i'm getting the error at  
                      Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text);
                      Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_discount.Text); //
                      Discountgiven = Cost * (Discount / Convert.ToDecimal(100));
                      DiscountTotal = Cost - Discountgiven;
                      Total = DiscountTotal * Quantity;
                  }

              }
          }
      }
  }

  private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Imagedisplay();
      using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
      {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_quantity.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_discount.Text))
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Cannot be empty");
          }
          else
          {                    
                  using (var command = new SqlCommand("Insert into product_result (Date, Image, Code, Name, Price, Discount, Quantity, Total) Values (@Date, @Image, @Code, @Name, @Price, @Discount, @Quantity, @Total)", con))
                  {                         
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date;
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data;
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text.Trim();
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_name.Text.Trim();
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_price.Text;
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txt_discount.Text.Trim();
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_quantity.Text.Trim();
                      command.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Total;
                      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      Totals();                      
                  }
                  using (var selects = new SqlCommand("Update employee_product set quantity = quantity - @Quantity where Codeitem= @Codeitem", con))
                  {
                      selects.Parameters.Add("@Codeitem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text;
                      selects.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_quantity.Text;
                      selects.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      this.Close();                          
                  }                   
              _view.Display();
          }
      }          
  }
  ```

Comment: What is the variable DiscountTotal and what is its value while debugging?

Comment: I'm passing the results of Cost * (Discount / Convert.ToDecimal(100)) to that variable DiscountTotal, the value of it is 0 while debugging

Comment: and the line below: txt_quantity.Text?

Comment: Where ? which one ?

Comment: Where you write: This is where i'm getting the error at..

Comment: Where i get the my quantity to the other table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]) . Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Dont put any further information into *comments*. Make sure your **question** contains all relevant information instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a NumericUpDown instead of a textbox to capture integer/decimal values. It handles all the validation for you stopping users from entering non-numeric values. You can set the maximum and minimum values you require and you don't have to worry about no values being entered as the NumericUpDown will always have a default value.

If you're using integers then you just need to cast to an int when you retrieve the value, otherwise it returns a decimal. So your code would be:

```
Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(numericupdown1.Value);
Discount = numericupdown2.Value;
```

If you're hellbent on using textboxes then you need to remove whitespace with `.Trim()`

```
Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text.Trim());
```

And use `int.TryParse` instead;

```
int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(txt_quantity.Text.Trim(), out value)
{
    // Successful conversion so value now contains your integer
}
```

You can do the same with decimals.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really really appreciate it